# Listing posts with wp-cli

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, wp-cli

I use `wp-cli` to export some posts from my WordPress database. I'm trying to understand the differences in behavior that are exposed in the example below:

```
$ wp post list --path=/var/www/home-web --post_type=any --fields=post_name,post_type,post_status
+----------------------------------+------------+-------------+
| post_name                        | post_type  | post_status |
+----------------------------------+------------+-------------+
| background                       | attachment | inherit     |
| privacy-policy                   | page       | publish     |
| macbook_flat_home                | attachment | inherit     |
| engine                           | page       | publish     |
| home                             | page       | publish     |
+----------------------------------+------------+-------------+

$ wp post list --path=/var/www/home-web --post_type=page --fields=post_name,post_type,post_status
+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| post_name | post_type | post_status |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| home      | page      | publish     |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+

$ wp post list --path=/var/www/home-web --post_type=polylang_mo --fields=post_name,post_type,post_status
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| post_name     | post_type   | post_status |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| polylang_mo_5 | polylang_mo | private     |
| polylang_mo_2 | polylang_mo | private     |
+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I see two problems:

- the first request doesn't show any custom post type (`polylang_mo` is a custom post type)
- the second request shows only 1 page (instead of 3)

Note for those unfamiliar with `wp-cli`: `wp post list` is basically a wrapper around `WP_Query` (see [source code](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli/blob/master/php/commands/post.php#L295)).

Comment: Regarding the first question, I suspect this is because `polylang_mo` is a private custom post type. Unless I explicitly request this post type, it won't be included.

Comment: And regarding the second, `--skip-plugins=polylang` solved it. I'll create an answer. Rubber ducking always works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the first request doesn't show any custom post type (polylang_mo is a custom post type)

`polylang_mo` is a private custom post type so unless I explicitly request this post type, it won't be included.

> the second request shows only 1 page (instead of 3)

Polylang was actually filtering the results. Adding `--skip-plugins=polylang` makes the 3 posts appear.